# Azure media player not playing uploaded video on MS Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-media-services

I'm trying to use Azure Media Services. For demo purpose I've uploaded a video directly on the portal then clicked to encode this uploaded video in 'H264 Smooth Streaming 720p' preset.
This scheduled a encoding job which generated another (off-course larger) file which I published to get the manifest file URL.

I can play this video on the portal itself but when I use the [given URL](http://mspocforknorish.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/72496130-cb2d-455e-9ccd-420fcb506f1d/BigBuckBunny.ism/Manifest) I get the following error:

> A network error caused the video download to fail part-way. Please check your network connection or try again later. (0x20200000)

I'm taking help from [this Channel9 video](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/DaveVoyles/Encoding-video-with-Azure-Media-Services).

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add `&format=smooth` to your URL and it should work!

http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmspocforknorish.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F72496130-cb2d-455e-9ccd-420fcb506f1d%2FBigBuckBunny.ism%2FManifest&format=smooth

Otherwise, on the page check "Advanced Options" checkbox and select `Smooth` from the `Format` dropdown and click on "Update" button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

When you paste your URL into the URL input, delete the existing sample URL that is already there. The existing URL looks like placeholder text but it is not. I fell into that trap too.

Here is a screenshot of your video playing [and here is the URL of it playing](http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmspocforknorish.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F72496130-cb2d-455e-9ccd-420fcb506f1d%2FBigBuckBunny.ism%2FManifest).

[image: The video playing on my machine.]

Comment: Thanks for quick test Shaun Luttin. I doubt my intranet firewall setup now.

Comment: Does the link in my answer play on your machine?

Comment: I see same error in your link. Its firewall i think, wasted 6 hours yesterday, thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: I just tried your link outside firewall setup, but again same error.

Comment: Hmm. It's reliable on my machine.